# How to automate seek bar on Appium 8.3.0

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I've been trying to find a way to automate a seekbar(Android) so that i can drag it left and right for its value. I'm not using TouchActions as based from my experience and recent documentations, it is already deprecated along with the MobileElements. My code also is not working,

Here is my code:

```
    public void seekBar(WebElement element) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: swipeGesture", ImmutableMap.of(
            "element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId(),
            "left", element.getLocation().getX() + 50,
            "top", element.getLocation().getY() + 50,
            "width", element.getSize().getWidth(),
            "height", element.getSize().getHeight(),
            "direction", "right",
            "percent", 0.75
        ));
}
```